# I need to add billing address in stripe checkout V2 in PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe V2 PHP library using the following
https://phppot.com/demo/stripe-payment-gateway-integration-using-php/

But I can't add the billing address option. I have heard that stripe has deprecated the billing address option, however i want to know is there any way to enable collecting the billing address in the checkout form?

Thanks